# Have The Hulk and The Thing ever fought before?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, the-thing

I was wondering who would win between a fight between these two guys with such monstrous strength? They both are almost of equal strength but hulk has increasing strength with increasing anger and The Thing has a body that is literally made of rock.

Have The Hulk and The Thing ever fought before, and if so, who won?

Comment: They've fought so often before that [there are lists of their top 10 fights](https://eoinvahey.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/top-10-hulk-vs-thing-battles-2/).

Comment: For every "Have X and Y ever fought?" where X and Y are characters in the same universe, the answer is almost certainly "yes" (unless either character was introduced very recently.) I don't see a point in asking a question for every combination of X and Y.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. They've fought plenty. So often, in fact, that entire [Top <strike>10</strike>11 Fight lists](https://eoinvahey.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/top-10-hulk-vs-thing-battles-2/) exist for their battles.

Of the 11 sampled battles, The Hulk wins handily 7 of the 11 times. In the instances where there was no clear winner, the Hulk was usually winning for most of the battle. There was one draw, and only one time when the Thing clearly won.

- World War Hulk #2: Hulk
- Fantastic Four #12: None
- Fantastic Four #112: Hulk
- Fantastic Four # 166-167: None
- Marvel Fanfare # 21: Hulk (Edge)
- Fantastic Four #320: The Thing
- The Incredible Hulk #350: Hulk
- HULK/THING Hard Knocks #1-4: Hulk (Edge)
- Fantastic Four #534-535: Hulk
- Incredible Hulk Annual #18: Draw
- Fantastic Four #25: Hulk

The issue is that while The Thing is incredibly powerful, he has an upper-limit on his strength, while in Earth-616, at least, the Hulk has no known upper-limit. This best shown in *World War Hulk* where Hulk decimates everyone and everything in his path, including The Thing.

Comment: Is World War hulk a movie?

Comment: No, it's a [limited series from 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Hulk).

Comment: There is an animated movie for Planet Hulk, the precursor to World War Hulk.

Comment: If I remember correctly, an additional reason cited at least once is that "the Thing gets tired; Hulk doesn't".